# What do I have to say when accepting my employer's request to be a LINE friend?

Tags: greetings

My employer sent a request with a message saying "田中です。"　What do I have to say when accepting my employer's request to be a LINE friend?

Comment: (For everybody wondering what LINE is.) What's LINE?

Comment: LINE is an instant messaging system similar to WeChat or What'sApp. You can make calls, send photos and stickers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your employer's name is 田中 (Tanaka), you should probably say something along the lines of よろしくお願いします, 田中さん or something similar to the formalities you said when you first met your boss.

Unless your employer added you on LINE for colloquial reasons (such as to hang out) then you should address them formally.

Comment: So you actually suggest that we address our employer as "family name + さん"?  We do not do that in Japan.

Comment: I've never been to Japan so this is only an assumption. Please provide a more correct answer (I'll learn from it too)

Comment: @Doge l'électeur may be referring to addressing employers/bosses by their title, such as 社長、部長、課長、次長、教育長、◯◯長・・・Also, just writing よろしくお願いします (without the boss's name afterward) may be more appropriate and maybe that is what l'électeur was getting at.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't think about it that way, thanks.